# Using Media Queries To Only Include JS Files On Desktop

Tags: javascript

I am trying to use the media attribute to only execute my javascript on to desktop devices, not on mobile ones.

this is what I have :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

if (screen.width > 980) { 

  document.write('<script type="text/javascript">  .......  </script>');  
 } 

</script>
```

the Porblem is that it only execute the script on mobile :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `window.innerWidth`,

```
if (window.innerWidth > 980) { 
  document.write('<script type="text/javascript">  .......  </script>');  
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for fast replay but I have the same result :( only work on mobile and not on desktop

Comment: sorry it did work :) I did have a extra script that did mess up the results :(

Comment: No problem. Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

```
    if(navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/webOS/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/Windows Phone/i)){
document.write('<script type="text/javascript">  mobile  </script>');
    }else{
    document.write('<script type="text/javascript">  desktop  </script>');
    }
```

Comment: Try this with device detection.